# Importing Compass CSS3 mixins with Foundation

Tags: sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I have Foundation installed and working, but I'm trying to use Compass CSS3 mixins within the same project and can't seem to figure out how to include  them.

I thought compass was installed already because prior to setting up Foundation I entered:
     `gem install compass` and I when using SASS I run `compass watch` into project folder. All Foundation mixins seems to compile SCSS with Compass..

I created a new compass project and merged the SCSS files and then tried to add:

```
@import "compass/css3"
```

Any help as to what I should run in the command line or add into files to access these mixons would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the sass/compass version of foundation 4 and created a project by using

`compass create myproject -r zurb-foundation --using foundation`

Then you would add `@import "compass/css3"` to the `stylesheets/app.scss` at the top of the file.

This allows you to use any of the [css3 mixins](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/) in your file, such as:

```
.myclass {
  @include border-radius(12);
}
```

You must run `compass watch` or run `compass compile` in your project directory after you make the changes to have the new css generated.

`@import` is loading the libary and `@include` is the method that generates css within your class.

UPDATE:

I am showing a modified `app.scss` file (truncated) so you can see how I made the modifications:

```
// Global Foundation Settings
@import "settings";

// Comment out this import if you don't want to use normalize
@import "normalize";

// Comment out this import if you are customizing you imports below
@import "foundation";

// Import Compass CSS3 Stuff
@import "compass/css3";

// Import specific parts of Foundation by commenting the import "foundation"
// and uncommenting what you want below. You must uncomment the following if customizing

// @import "foundation/components/global"; // *always required
// ...
// @import "foundation/components/dropdown";

.myclass {
  @include border-radius(12);
}
```

which generates the following in `stylesheets/app.css`:

```
/* line 52, ../sass/app.scss */
.myclass {
  -webkit-border-radius: 12;
  -moz-border-radius: 12;
  -ms-border-radius: 12;
  -o-border-radius: 12;
  border-radius: 12;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that and received `an invalid syntax error saying "expected selector or at-rule"`. I'm sure `compass watch` was running because the css is changing as I save the scss files. Any thought?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. if this still does not work, maybe post your `config.rb` file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this wasn't the problem, but it helped confirm my SCSS files were correct and the issue was the paths. In the project directory I just typed "install compass", which I had done earlier, but maybe in the wrong place or sequence.

Answer (score -1):

In the project directory I typed `install compass` again and that did the trick.

At some point in the project I either mistyped or did this in the wrong sequence or directory.

I thought Compass itself was already installed because I had installed Foundation, but even if it was, the files weren't accessible within the project.

After that Compass was available via the path I had previously setup in my SCSS file "compass/css3".